# import from xml and insert into list in javascript

Tags: office-365

I want to create a page in javascript (sharepoint hosted app) that receives a xml and parse this xml to create list elements, do you have any code that can help me.

also I'm thinking in doing it with infopath (new page), any ideas?

Comment: I've found that I can not do this in javascript because to get the upload of a file can be done only on server side. thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

where do you receive the xml from? You can use the JSOM to create list items.

Example for parsing xml:
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp

Retreive XML With ajax:
http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/04/read-and-process-xml-using-jquery-ajax.html

Example for creating sharepoint list items whit javascript:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh185011(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh185011%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: I got a page that when a form is submitted it sends a xml with the data submitted, this xml is sent via post request and I want to receive the xml and create list items in javascript

Comment: so why don't you do it with javascript?

Comment: I want to use javascript, but I don't know how to do is to get what is uploaded to the page, I mean in net there is a request.contenttype or a request.content where I get what its uploaded, in javascript how it is done?

Comment: so how is it uploaded? You maybe have to post a bit of your code so that we know what the actual case is.